# How to get a series from a pandas dataframe using a series of column names?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice, data-wrangling

I have a pandas dataframe `df`  with numeric data. I also have a series `s` with the same index as `df` and values consisting of `df` column labels, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[0, 1, 2], columns=[0, 1, 2],
    data=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
)
s = pd.Series(index=[0, 1, 2]), data=[0, 1, 2])
```

How can I use `s` to slice `df` and get another series `s1` that contains `df` values corresponding to the `(index, value)` pairs in `s` as their `.loc()` identifiers in `df`, i.e.

```
s1 = pd.Series(index=[0, 1, 2], data=[1, 5, 9])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.lookup` to lookup the values in `df` based on `s.index` and `s`, then create a new series from this lookup values:

```
s1 = pd.Series(df.lookup(s.index, s), index=s.index)
```

Another idea using `DataFrame.stack` and indexing using `DataFrame.loc`:

```
s1 = df.stack().loc[zip(s.index, s)].droplevel(1)
```

Result:

```
print(s1)

0    1
1    5
2    9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! That should do it.